# Infinite set of positive integers - choose infinitely many to be relative primes or not

Tags: infinity, gcd-and-lcm, set-partition

Given a set of infinitely many positive integers. Is it always possible to find a subset of this set which contains infinitely many numbers such that any two numbers in this subset are relative primes or any two numbers in this subset have a greatest common divisor greater than 1?

There is a beautiful solution for this problem, my teacher told me that it is hard but you don’t have to use anything.

So I am looking for solutions not using well known theorems... thanks!

Comment: Hint. Consider two cases. (1) Some prime divides infinitely many members of the set. (2) No prime divides infinitely many members of the set. I don't think I have to say more about case (1). In case (2), construct your subset by choosing one number at a time, so that each number you choose is relatively prime to all of the numbers already chosen.

Answer (score 0):

This is an application of the infinite Ramsey theorem, see 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem

Color a pair blue if they are coprime and red if they are not.

Comment: You used a well known theorem, that’s what I wanted to avoid. But it is a simple beautiful solution anyway, so thanks